# Passing a string to a function in C++(object vs string)

Tags: c++

What is the difference between the following two in C++?

```
fun(L"text1")
```

VS

```
std::wstring var = "text1"
fun(var)
```

In the first case, it is being passed as an object while the second case passes it  as a wstring.

How should `fun()` be defined to handle both?

EDIT:
I have two function definitions

```
fun(void*)
fun(std::wstring)

std::wstring t = "bla";
fun(t);
fun(L"msg");
```

When fun(t) is called it goes to the definition of fun(std::wstring)
But when fun(L"msg") is called it goes to fun(Void*). Instead I want it to goto fun(std::wstring)

Comment: A [`std::wstring()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) can be implicitly created from a wide character literal.

Comment: When I pass fun("text"), does it get recognized as object or string?

Answer (score 0):

The first is passed as a *wide-string literal*. In the second case, you pass by value (and hence copy) or by reference an `std::wstring` object.

To handle both, you have to define two overloads of your function:

```
void fun(const wchar_t* s);
void fun(const std::wstring& s);
```

or you can just define the `wstring` version, because the literal will implicitly convert to a `wstring`.

Answer (score 0):

To handle both you should define the fun method as:

```
void fun(const std::wstring& str);
```

then in both cases you would be passing a const reference to a wstring because the compiler is allowed to implicitly cast one type to another if the type being cast to has a constructor that takes one argument of the type being cast from unless that constructor is marked as explicit.

Example:

```
class wstring
{
public:
    // constructor not marked as explicit and takes one argument of type whar_t*
    wstring(const wchar_t* str);
};

wstring myString = L"hello world"; // implicit cast from wchar_t* to wstring
```

The only difference between the two examples you've given is that in the first you are passing an rvalue (which you can only bind to a const reference) and in the second you are passing an lvalue (which you can bind to both const and non-const reference).

Comment: Here is my issue with this, I have two overloaded functions fun(void*) and fun(std::wstring). When I call fun(L"bla") it goes to fun(void*) instead of fun(std::wstring).

Comment: Could you not be more explicit and call it like this: fun(std::wstring(L"bla)). The compiler is allowed to implicitly convert a wchar_t* to void* so it's valid for it to choose fun(void*) instead of fun(std::wstring).

Answer (score 0):

In given examples there is no much difference, because compiler will generate constant data containing your literal and use it in both cases.

In the first case, raw literal will be used from string table of your module. This is as fast as possible code without heap allocation (actually no allocations).

In the second case, compiler will allocate string buffer in the heap, which results into malloc() call and strcpy(). This will increase time of your code and cause more memory fragmentation.

You should use std string classes only when you really need to use their useful methods, otherwise, TCHAR buffers are just excellent choice.